# Does Redux have setState?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I noticed in React, components have internal state managed by setState, but my understanding is that Redux has a global state. Does one interact with redux using setState as well?

Comment: No. You need to dispatch actions to change redux state.

Comment: In redux you need to dispatch action that update the store, I strongly recommend you to go through the official documentation, https://redux.js.org/

Comment: right.. with actions. thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 2):

You can have both, actually, there are plenty of situations where you to have component state + global state of application inside the redux store. You can get more information about this topic here

> It's also possible to apply Redux's principles and concept of reducers
>   to the task of updating local component state as well, along the lines
>   of this.setState( (previousState) => reducer(previousState,
>   someAction))

https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html

Comment: my understanding is that redux state isn't the same variables as the ones in internal state. but redux state is usually mapped via props.

Comment: Redux is a state container for application and this.state is a state container for a component.